# Hazelcast - Indexing on object field / property

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I was wondering whether this was possible in Hazelcast. Say we have a Java entity:

```
public class BrtWeekDefinitions {

private Long id;
private BrtTimeCharts brtTimeCharts;
private BrtDayDefinitions brtDayDefinitions;
private Long weekDay;
}
```

And this entity is loaded in-memory in a map of type: Long, BrtWeekDefinitions.

BrtTimeCharts  and BrtDayDefinitions entities are also loaded in their respective maps.

Would this then work?

```
//Where mapObject is a map of type <Long,BrtWeekDefinitions>
mapObject.addIndex("BrtTimeCharts.id", false); 
mapObject.addIndex("BrtDayDefinitions.id", false);
```

Or would I have to do such?

```
//Where mapObject is a map of type <Long,BrtTimeCharts>
mapObject.addIndex("id", false);
```

and:

```
//Where mapObject is a map of type <Long,BrtDayDefinitions>
mapObject.addIndex("id", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfred Salah,

This will work

```
//Where mapObject is a map of type <Long,BrtWeekDefinitions>
mapObject.addIndex("brtTimeCharts.id", false); // use property name not type
mapObject.addIndex("brtDayDefinitions.id", false);
```

More info about nested indexes [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#indexing-queries) and [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-in-collections-and-arrays)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers,
Vik

Comment: Cheers Vik! This works. EDIT:  I got carried away with Hazelcast's Criteria API object syntax :) !